# Echo variable name, not value, from for loop in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

```
a=1
b=2
c=3

for db in $a $b $c; do
echo VARIABLE NAME
blah 
blah  
blah
```

I need this for a script I am writing. I have some Client names set at the top to database names for the varialble.   I am running a ps -ef and a few other things, but I need it to echo out which client name it is on in the loop.  So in example above, it would echo out "a", then its other commands, then on the second loop echo "b" .....etc

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use variable indirection:

```
for var in a b c ; do
    echo $var ${!var}
done
```

Comment: Ok, this works for me when I remove the $'s from a b and c. When I run it thought, it echo's  a  then 1, but it stops there and doesn't iterate through the rest of the loop.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind. I had a problem in an if statement where I was calling the var name instead of value.  Thanks for the information, it was exactly what I needed!